# Zabbix does not send emails

Tags: email, monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to configure zabbix with email notifications. I read many docs about it already, but I must be missing something still, because it doesn't work...

What I have configured at the moment:

- media type: email, with host=`localhost`, helo=`localhost`, email=`zabbix@somedomain.com`
- user with email assigned for all events apart from "not classified"
- sendmail is running on the host
- one remote host is monitored through `zabbix_agent` - I'm turning it off to cause a trigger to fire
- zabbix panel "beeps" and show the failing check correctly
- nothing is written to the sendmail logs (it does write a message if I try connecting with telnet, so it works in general)
- nothing related seems to be written to the `zabbix_server` log

What else can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one was in the group which was assigned to an action. After setting proper groups for notifications, emails are sent out.

Comment: Another place to check in this case is the "notifications" tab under admin in the frontend.

Comment: What the hell is `Noone` ?

Comment: @Radio no one typoed